# Open last added file containing a name via vba

Tags: vba, excel

Files are added daily to a folder, they all contain a name that beggins with "mad" I need to open the last one in order to execute my macros. My code can open the file that it´s file name contains "mad", but it doesn´t open the newest one added to the folder:

```
  sub openfilewithnamestring
           sFound = Dir(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\mad*.xlsb")    'should open the latest file added in the folder that constains "MAD" in the name
        If sFound <> "" Then
            Workbooks.Open Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & sFound
end if

    end sub
```

Example:
MAD0902 16.10.2017
MAD0902 17.10.2017

Comment: User your method to open all of the files that begin with `MAD`; use string functions to tease out the date and save the most recent.

Comment: I need to open the latest file to execute other macros, I don´t need to save it again

Comment: Then don't open them. Just cycle through them using your Dir method.  This is, of course, assuming that the `latest` is as defined by the latest date in the file name.

Comment: Thanks  Ron Rosenfeld, sounds easy enough, but I´d not be able to implement such code by myself, is there a starting point?

Comment: Your starting point is the code you have already written. Where are you having a problem?  If it is looping through the files, there are plenty of examples that can be found by a simple search of this forum.  If it is in how to use string functions, I would start by reading the relevant VBA HELP topics.

Comment: [this](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/identifying_the_newest_file_in_a_directory/) website has 2 methods (one depreciated) which will get the latest file in a directory